# How to point route53 records to bucket for *any*subdomain?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have an S3 bucket called [www.mybucket.com](http://www.mybucket.com)
I have an A record: name = [www.mybucket.com](http://www.mybucket.com). It answers well with the index.html contained in the bucket.

Now I want to send *any* subdomain to that bucket.

I tried first with specific subdomains:

- an A record ALIAS

  - name: alias.mytestbucket.com
  - alias target [www.mytestbucket.com](http://www.mytestbucket.com).
  - RESULT: 404, NoSuchBucket, The specified bucket does not exist
- a CNAME record with NO alias

  - name: cname.mytestbucket.com
  - value: [www.mytestbucket.com](http://www.mytestbucket.com)
  - RESULT: 404, NoSuchBucket, The specified bucket does not exist
- a CNAME record with alias

  - name: cnamealias.mytestbucket.com
  - alias target: cname.mytestbucket.com. (the only option offered...)
  - RESULT: 404, NoSuchBucket, The specified bucket does not exist

no more ideas...

The final goal will be to redirect all subdomains to the bucket [www.mybucket.com](http://www.mybucket.com).
But also ability to send different subdomains to different buckets will be good...

Comment: It's not likely that you should actually be trying this. It should be fine to refer to files in your S3 bucket by a single canonical URL.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. The way this works is that the client resolves *[www.mybucket.com](http://www.mybucket.com)* to a generic S3 endpoint that serves millions of other buckets. It then sends [*Host HTTP header*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) `Host: www.mybucket.com`. The S3 service then matches the host header `www.mybucket.com` to your bucket name `www.mybucket.com` and serves the `index.html` file from there. That's how it works.

Even if you make A / ALIAS / CNAME `*.mybucket.com` pointing to the `www.mybucket.com` it in the end *still resolves to the generic S3 address* - that's how DNS works, it doesn't care about any intermediate names.

Now if you try to access `xyz.mybucket.com` your browser sends Host header `Host: xyz.mybucket.com` -> S3 can't map it to any existing bucket -> you get *NoSuchBucket* error.

So no, you can't do it this way.

---

*Possible Workaround:* you can use a [reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) e.g. on EC2 or in Fargate container and point `*.mybucket.com` to this proxy hostname. The proxy will then make a backend request to S3 and serve the file to the client. The downside is that everything has to go through your proxy, sacrificing the *high-availability* of S3 API.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

@MLu 's answer is correct, I'm just adding a possible workaround.

It does not work for OP's *any* subdomain requirement, and it's not great for it's not scalable and maintainable, but works good for small website with little-to-none changes over time.

Solution is to force redirect using JS, creating an S3 bucket for every subdomain you want to expose, each one serving a static website (same configuration of the main/original one), containing only a one-liner index.html file. Example:

New bucket with name "some.example.com":

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script type="text/javascript">window.location="http://www.example.com"</script></body></html>
```